# Issue With angular mdl-stepper when using ui- router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use mdl-stepper, when I add the stepper in the index.html page its working fine. Please find the plunker link below

```
"https://plnkr.co/edit/m7EGqw?p=preview"
```

But when I do the same thing inside a separate html and use ui-router, its not working.

```
"https://plnkr.co/edit/ixMI8FKbhyTgL5sYieVa?p=preview"
```

Please let me know what is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepper uses (`componentHandler`) the pattern of Material Design Lite to registration new components and upgrade automatically on document load and components that may be added after initial page load.

In your case, Stepper was added by asynchronous request (after initial page load). To do so, you must upgrade manually the Stepper component to work as well.

Code in your async. request callback:

```
// The Stepper registers itself. Since you are adding dynamically, then you 
// need to upgrade it. This line will upgrade all components that must.
componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
```